# AES decryption of MixColumn

Tags: aes

In the encryption of MixColumn you use the constants 01, 02 and 03. I don't understand why the inverse of 01 becomes both 0D and 09. I also don't understand how you get 01, 02 and 03 in the first place which is probably why the decryption doesn't make sense to me. I would appreciate any help with understanding how to calculate these values.

Comment: Note that the elements of the inverse matrix are not the inverses of the individual elements; hence 0D and 09 are not "inverses" of 01

Comment: and, you calculate the inverse of the matrix in $GF(2^8)$ see [How to invert matrix in finite field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1583159/how-to-invert-matrix-in-finite-field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MixColumns` $MC$ and `InvMixColumns` $IMC$ implement matrix multiplications. These two matrices defined over Galois Field $GF(2^8)$ and they are inverse of each other.

$$MC \times IMC = I_4$$

To find the inverse, one can use the [Gaussian Elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Gaussian_elimination) method. But finding the inverse a bit tricky, since you will need the inverse of the pivot elements. The inverse in $GF(2^8)$ can be found by using the [Extended Euclidean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) Algorithm.

In general, instead of calculating the inverse, the invMixColumn matrix copied from [FIPS 197](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/fips/nist.fips.197.pdf) or  [AES submission of  Rijndael](https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/projects/cryptographic-standards-and-guidelines/documents/aes-development/rijndael-ammended.pdf).